# How to parallelize spark.read.parquet()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

My Spark job reads a folder with parquet data partitioned by the column *partition*:

```
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Prepare Id Mapping")
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    spark.read
      .parquet(sourceDir)
      .filter($"field" === "ss_id" and $"int_value".isNotNull)
      .select($"int_value".as("ss_id"), $"partition".as("date"), $"ct_id")
      .coalesce(1)
      .write
      .partitionBy("date")
      .parquet(idMappingDir)
```

I've noticed that only one task is created so it's very slow. There is a lot of subfolders like *partition=2019-01-07* inside the source folder, and each subfolder contains a lot of files with the extension *snappy.parquet*. I submit the job *--num-executors 2 --executor-cores 4*, and RAM is not an issue. I tried reading from both S3 and the local filesystem. I tried adding *.repartition(nPartitions)*, removing *.coalesce(1)* and *.partitionBy("date")* but the same.

Could you suggest how I can get Spark read these parquet files in parallel?

Comment: nothing looks odd. try reading sourceDir/2019-01-07 if you see a difference

Comment: @Salim It would helped in my case because I needed the partition column in the dataframe.

Comment: good find on 'merge schema'. Please change your question to add this concern that each partition may have a different schema to help others find answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've figured out the correct code:

```
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Prepare Id Mapping")
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    spark.read
      .option("mergeSchema", "true")
      .parquet(sourceDir)
      .filter($"field" === "ss_id" and $"int_value".isNotNull)
      .select($"int_value".as("ss_id"), $"partition".as("date"), $"ct_id")
      .write
      .partitionBy("date")
      .parquet(idMappingDir)
```

Hope this will save someone time in future.

Comment: coalesce taken out?

Comment: @thebluephantom Just taking coalesce out didn't solve the problem but together with adding .option("mergeSchema", "true") is did.

Comment: May be highlight that. Cheers

Comment: I tried to make these 2 rows (with coalesce and option) be shown in bold but it didn't work inside the code snippet.